# Why can't I assign a scanf statement directly to a variable in C?

Tags: c, scanf

How is `int a = scanf("%d", &a);` different from `int a; scanf("%d", &a);`?

I need some help trying to understand how these two things work behind the scenes as they clearly output different results.

Comment: The first one is wrong, the second one is right. Simple as that.  Look at the definition of `scanf`: the values scanned are returned via arguments 2..N, which are always pointers to the variables which receive the scanned values.  The overall return value, on the other hand, is a count of the number of values successfully converted.  Saying `a = scanf("%d",&a)` is quite meaningless, because you're trying to use variable `a` both as the value returned *and* as the count (0 or 1) of values successfully returned..

Comment: @SteveSummit the first one could be useful if you want to consume an integer from the input, and you do care if the input form was incorrect but don't care about the actual value

Comment: @M.M But in that case you'd want to use `a = scanf("%d", &dummy)` or perhaps `a = scanf("%*d")`.  Trying to use the same variable for both is confusing and asking for trouble.

Answer (score 7):

`scanf` is a standard input function in C.

The first thing you should learn about `scanf` is the 'return value'. Refer to the manual page for `scanf` by accessing `man scanf` if you're on Linux.

`scanf` returns the number of values read in from standard input. i.e your `scanf` would return 1, as only one value has been read in, in this case.

So if you run

```
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

first the expression `int a` would create a new int variable of size int (4 bytes). Then `scanf("%d", &a)` would input a value of size int from your standard input. Say you enter 5.

But then as you are setting `a` to whatever `scanf` is returning, i.e the number of values read from the standard input which is 1. so `a` would always be 1 no matter what value you enter into input.

Now, as for

```
int a; 
scanf("%d", &a);
```

What you are doing is, first creating `a` with `int a`. Then you are "NOT" saving the return value of `scanf` anywhere. That means from `scanf`, any value you enter is read into `a`. And that's it. The return value (for `scanf`, the return value is the number of input values; in this case we are only entering one value so it's 1) is not being fed to a or any other variable. So `a` now has the value what you entered earlier from your standard input.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you should always check the return value of `scanf`. If it doesn't return the value you expect, then an error occurred. For example, if you call `scanf(%d", &a)` and the input is `xyz`, it will return 0.

Comment: And when `scanf()` returns zero, it does not assign to the variable `a`, which will still be uninitialized.  There's also EOF to consider; i`scanf()` will return EOF on reaching end of file without having converted anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a; scanf("%d", &a);
```

In the above code an integer variable is declared and its address is passed to scanf function,because inside scamf function the value of a get modified.So in order to reflect the change in the main function you have to pass the address. scanf function reads input from the standard input stream stdin and the value of a will be changed to that.

```
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

In this piece of code also the working of scanf is similar.But after scanf function,it's return value is assigned to a. scanf function return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.so here the value of a will be 1 or zero.